# Converting CURDATE() to my local date with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timezone

I'm using Godaddy's MySQL database. Since their timezone is MST UTC -7, I needed to modify my code. I figured out how to do it when using NOW() function. However Im struggling while converting result of CURDATE() to my local date. Topics in the website didnt help it. I dont have privilege to change timezone of mysql since it is shared host. The problem about CURDATE() is, since there is 10 hours difference between server and my country, dates will be different at somepoint.

**What I have tried so far**

**First attempt**

```
SELECT convert_tz(CURDATE(),'-07:00','+03:00')
```

this query returns following output in the mysql.

```
convert_tz(CURDATE(),'-07:00','+03:00')     
2016-05-14 10:00:00
```

I didnt try yet since still dates are the same but this code probably done the work. But the problem is about the time comes after date.CURDATE should return only date. I think it returns the differences between two timezones which equals to 10 hours but I think it is gonna cause problem when Im comparing 2 dates.

**Second attempt**

```
SELECT convert_tz(CURDATE(),'MST','EEST');
```

Since server's timezone is MST and my timezone is EEST, I tried in this way but it returns NULL.

The question is what should I do to just return date without that 10:00:00 there. or is there any better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your approach.

First, `CURDATE()` returns a date, not a datetime.

Second, you need to convert the current *date and time* from the server's time zone to your time zone *before* truncating the time portion.  This means using `NOW()` inside, not `CURDATE()`.

Third, you need to use the correct abbreviations for the correct time zones for both sides of the conversion, for the entire year.  `CONVERT_TZ()` will return `NULL` if either time zone is unrecognized.

In this case, MST/MDT is called "MST7MDT" and EET/EEST is called "EET" in the MySQL time zone tables.  It's surprising that Go Daddy doesn't set their server clocks to UTC -- that's sort of a de facto standard for server clocks, but assuming not, "MST7MDT" is probably the most correct value.

```
mysql> SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'MST7MDT','EET'));
+-----------------------------------------+
| DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'MST7MDT','EET')) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2016-05-14                              |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or, you could use the more intuitive localized names for the time zones.  I believe these values would also be correct, an would accommodate summer and time changes correctly:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'America/Denver','Europe/Bucharest'));
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'America/Denver','Europe/Bucharest')) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-05-14                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The second form is actually more correct.  Additionally, you should take the UTC timestamp from the server and convert that, rather than trusting any server time zone setting.  Consider starting from `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: I didnt think in this way. This is better idea. But eventhough I dont see any reason, both of them returns NULL value. However this has worked `SELECT DATE(convert_tz(NOW(), '-07:00' ,'+03:00'))` . But I think it might cause problem in future since there is no very specific timezone in the query.

Comment: If `CONVERT_TZ()` isn't working, try `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mysql.time_zone_name;`.  If the answer is "0" then you need to [load the time zone tables](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html) or contact vendor support to have them properly configured.

Comment: @MattJohnson, thanks.  I agree with that assessment.  I have used `IFNULL(NULLIF(@@TIME_ZONE,'SYSTEM'),@@SYSTEM_TIME_ZONE)` in the past as the second arg to `CONVERT_TZ()` with good results, but omitted that to avoid complicating the solution.

Comment: I meant more like `SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 'UTC', 'Europe/Bucharest'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert you date into string using CAST, and then get a substring.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( CAST(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE(),'-07:00','+03:00') AS char), ':', -1)
```

Should return

```
2016-05-14 10:00
```